# Taxabilty of Gift from Son to Parents

Tags: gift-tax

My son has become NRI three years back.He wants to withdraw his accumulated balance of EPF and Employees Pension Fund in which he was a member since 2006.

He wants to gift the amount so withdrawn to his parents in equal proportion.

Will these amounts ne taxable as Gift Tax?

Comment: Tax questions need to identify the countries involved.

Comment: The Giver(son) is in UK and the Receivers(parents) are in India.